# cpanel cron command line delete file

Tags: php, cron, cpanel, delete-file

Short and long of it
cpanel cron tab, I am setting up a command to delete a log file generated by 3 cron jobs for phplist.

Not using a script, shouldnt need one, in cpanel you can simply enter a command with your functions.
Currently trying:

```
php -find /home/*myServerName*/public_html/lists/admin/logs/* -name cron.log -type f -delete
```

while testing running `*/1 * * * *`

I can either get command to delete the file but not get the email notification
OR
Get the email with "No input file specified." or some other error message woth no log file deleted

I have tried about 20 iterations, none successfully

Help!
Thanks

Comment: does what ever cron is running as have permission needed to delete the files? did you test from the command line

Comment: correct permissions are set.
was given permission to pipe into the account to run cl
response 
"could not open input file: ind"
No idea what ind is referencing

Answer (score 0):

Just add rm in front of the path

```
rm public_html/<folderName>/index.php
```

Answer (score -2):

You don't need `php`

Correct command:

```
find /home/*myServerName*/public_html/lists/admin/logs/ -type f -name cron.log -delete
```

Cron

```
* * * * * find /home/*myServerName*/public_html/lists/admin/logs/ -type f -name cron.log -delete
```

Comment: i think you mean `php`

Comment: Cron should have time setting other than all '*', every some time.

Comment: @Mulli five asterisks or wildcard is valid in crontab. Read MAN5 of crontab https://linux.die.net/man/5/crontab

Comment: @abkrim True. But waisting CPU resources.

Comment: @Mulli Can you prove what it says or indicate a link explaining that statement that contradicts the package's own documentation?

Comment: @abkrim The answer is in the question above. Searching for logfiles every minutes is not the answer to the above question

Comment: @Mulli my reply is not for question is for your reply. This a a comment for you reply, is not for other question.  "But waisting CPU resources". But not problem, I will not reply more you. Best regrads.